# How does the Reader functor instance satisfy fmap?

Tags: haskell

I am reading "Category Theory for Programmers" By Bartosz Milewski and on pg. 164 he introduces a natural transformation for the Reader Functor:

```
newtype Reader e a = Reader (e -> a)

instance Functor (Reader e) where
   fmap f (Reader g) = Reader (\x -> f (g x))
```

I am having a difficult time understanding the type signature of this transformation.

My best guess is something like:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Reader e -> a) -> (Reader e -> b)
```

I am confused that the functor is declared with Reader partially applied `Reader e` and then on line two there `f` and `g` which are the two function arguments. Then, there is a lambda expression with `x`. Since there is no value for `x`, I assume the `Reader(\x -> ....)` lambda expression is partially applied. Does `x` refer to some outside value? Where does `e` come into play?

So, how does the fmap instance satisfy `fmap => (a->b) -> f a -> f b`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, there are two separate constructors named `Reader`:

1. The type constructor with kind `Type -> Type -> Type`
2. The data constructor with type `(a -> b) -> Reader a b`.

`Reader e` is a partial application of the type constructor to get something with kind `Type -> Type`, which is suitable for defining a `Functor` instance.

`Reader g` is a pattern that matches a value of type `Reader e a`, which means `g` is bound to a value of type `e -> a`.

In order to construct a value of type `Reader e b`, we need to construct a value of type `e -> b`. We don't have access to a value of type `b` for that function to return, but we can get one using `f :: a -> b`. So, our function of type `e -> b` will take its `e` argument, pass it to `g :: e -> a`, and we'll pass that result to `f`.

It's slightly easier to see when you expand `Reader` to the function types, and write them in prefix (rather than infix) order.

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Reader e a -> Reader e b
     -- by isomorphism of Reader e x and e -> x
     :: (a -> b) -> (e -> a) -> (e -> b)
     -- using prefix notation
     :: (a -> b) -> ((->) e) a -> ((->) e) b
     -- generalizing from a specific functor to an abstract functor
     :: (a -> b) -> f a  -> f b
```

where `f` is the functor `(->) e` or `Reader e` whose instance we are defining.

Or arguably simpler,

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Reader e a -> Reader e b
     -- type constructor application is left-associative
     :: (a -> b) -> (Reader e) a -> (Reader e) b
     -- Reader e is the functor
     :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Answer (score 3):

**No**, here `f ~ Reader e`, so `f a` means `Reader e a`, and thus:

```
fmap @(Reader e) :: (a -> b) -> Reader e a -> Reader e b
```

It thus will with a function `f :: (a -> b)` transform a `Reader e a` to a `Reader e b`.

Now for the pattern `(Reader g)`, we know that `g` has type `g :: e -> a`, we thus need to produce a function `e -> b`. We can do that by creating a function that maps a variable `x` to `g x`, and then applies `f` on that result, such that `\x -> f (g x)` or shorter `f . g` has type `f . g :: e -> b`, which thus satisfies the type constraint.